# Can we create a Superglobal Boolean variable in php that can be manipulated from any php script?

Tags: php, superglobals

I have a php script that runs every minute to check something. What I need is, if the script finds what it is checking for then set a Boolean to true so that on subsequent run of the script it can know that earlier run has set the Boolean to true. As far as I understand $GLOBALS can only be accessed from the script. Currently I am using database to achieve this. Is there a better way ?

Comment: [php sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) may be what you're looking. It is classed as a super global

Comment: How is the script being ran? What is the reason to know something happened previously? ie what happens if it was set to what happened if it wasn' - does this need to be long term persistent or short? etc

Comment: Can you give an example. The php page is never accessed through browser. It just runs in the background.

Comment: If the script is running every minute, it's presumably running as CLI from Cron? Which means that you won't be able to use a session..? Database is probably your best bet, though you *could* use a text file if it's never likely to have locking or multiple user issues.

Comment: Yes it is running from cron.

Comment: Stick with your database solution

Comment: Database is fine but u need 2 crons here right?, you can also think about pub sub pattern(queue, not sure its an over engineering since dont know about how big the task), then you dont need 2 crons only one to publish the message subscriber(consumer) or subscribers will execute the job/s. Bit more work!
plus you can remove the cron jobs by directly publish the message If you have the control in the source code by implementing it directly in the source code.

Comment: I am not sure why you assumed I need two cron. Its just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 - Environment Variables**

What you might need is something which is present system-wide.
the first thing that came to my mind is **environment variables**. You can read and write them as needed. you can check them at any point, but it will be visible to other applications as well.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

The problem with session is that sessions are closely related to the requests. basically, the session gets started when the request arrived, and they are supposed to get destroyed when the request is over (in the sense that like the user has logged in or logged out)

But the question is about a cron job, which is basically a cli program. which don't have any requests associated with it.

**Solution 2 - File Based**

By having a file-based check, you can create a file, and add the flag inside file. or the file itself can be the flag.

**Solution 3 - By using a datastore**

If you have something like a **[Redis](https://redis.io/)** system running as part of the application,  you can use this to store the flag/condition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about PHP Sessions ($_SESSION) if it's a loop within the same session. You could use a session variable, assuming your PHP session has started.
Here's a basic example:

```
<?php

// start session
session_start();

// Should we check something once only?
if(!isset($_SESSION['checked'])){

   // Store timestamp incase we want to do the work
   // again every so often...
   $_SESSION['checked'] = time();

  // Do the work...
  // Your work code here...
}
?>
```

If it's running at different times or a CRON you can use a simple cached text file maybe? Again, this is just a basic example and there would be a number of other checks to do plus you need to manage the output yourself. I've done it with a very simple if / else to show the logic. All sorts of ways to do it though.

```
<?php
$checked = "/root/path/to/my/cachefile.txt";
$do_work = false;
$err     = false;

if($last_time = file_get_contents($checked)){

   // Optional: Check to see how long it was since we
   // did it last and if we need to do it
   // again, flag $do_work as TRUE

} else {
   if(file_put_contents($checked,time())){
     $do_work = true;
   } else {
     $err = true;
   }
}

// So at this stage we are either going to
// to the work, the work's already been done
// or we can't do the work because there
// was a problem
if($err){
  // report a problem as we are unable to 
  // log the work being done, even if it was
} else {
  if($do_work){
     // Do your work
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: It runs every minute on background. No browser is involved. Can I use session in this situation.

Comment: Although I suggested PHP sessions in the comments, I don't think they work when ran over CLI. Another solution may be advised.

Comment: Added file based check

Comment: So basically I need to put the Boolean to a text file or database and probably text file and using database don't have much performance issue. I think I will stick to my database solution.